# In phpMyAdmin and MySQL How to Add selected fields from two tables to other table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please, can someone Help?

I have 2 Tables with complete info about CITY (table1) and COORDINATES (table2).

In phpMyAdmin and MySQL how can I add 3 new columns: City Name, Latitude, Longitude to a new table with only Street and Number like this example:

TABLE 1 - **City**

```
ID  StateCODE   CityCODE    City Name
1      01          23         City1
2      01          09         City2
3      02          12         City3
4      03          10         City4
```

TABLE 2 - **Coordinates**

```
ID  StateCODE   CityCODE    Street  Number  Latitude    Longitude
1      01          23        AAAA     AAA    0.0000       0.0000
2      01          09        BBBB     BBC    0.0001       0.0001
3      02          12        DDDD     DDF    0.0002       0.0002
4      03          10        CCCC     CCV    0.0003       0.0003
```

I need to complete one new table were I already have this data:

TABLE 3 - **Address**

```
ID  Street  Number
1    DFAB     AAA
2    AAAA     AAA
3    CGFT     CGF
```

And add 3 new columns to complete all information like this:

```
ID  Street  Number  City Name   Latitude    Longitude
1    DFAB    AAA      ????        ????         ????
2    AAAA    AAA      ????        ????         ????
3    CGFT    CGF      ????        ????         ????
```

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add those columns in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Address ADD 'City Name' varchar(100), Latitude float, Longitude float;
```

Now add the values according to the condition:

```
UPDATE  Address
       JOIN Coordinates
       ON Address.Street = Coordinates.Street and Address.Number = Coordinates.Number
       JOIN City
       ON City.CityCODE = Coordinates.CityCODE and City.StateCODE = Coordinates.StateCODE
SET     Address.'City Name' = City.'City Name'
        Address.Latitude = Coordinates.Latitude
        Address.Longitude = Coordinates.Longitude
```

I haven't ran this code, so there maybe errors. This is just for giving you the idea behind it.

Comment: My pleasure! :)